# Let's put [airplane] into [airplane-mode]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I came across the [airplane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/airplane) tag, and the [tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/airplane/info) currently is:

> Airplane is a setting to disable the device's signal transmitting functions on mobile devices.
>
> Airplane mode is a setting available on most modern mobile electronic devices like cellphone, tablet and etc. that when engaged, suspends the device's signal transmitting functions (both WIFI and Cellular network), thereby disabling the device's capacity to place or receive calls or text messages or access internet, while still permitting use of other functions, and let user use the device in some restricted area like Airplane.

This tag has 108 questions, and just based on the first couple pages, there are a fair number of questions that don't have anything to do with airplane mode, but rather aviation-related stuff.

However, there is a much more thoughtfully-named [airplane-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/airplane-mode), but so far it only has two questions and no usage guidance.

Since an airplane is obviously something very different from airplane mode, I don't think that the [airplane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/airplane) tag is well-named. I suggest we change the [airplane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/airplane) guidance to describe things having to do with airplanes, or maybe even burninate it, and that we re-tag all the airplane mode [airplane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/airplane) questions to [airplane-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/airplane-mode), changing [airplane-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/airplane-mode)'s guidance accordingly, since that name makes more sense in the context.

Comment: For those programming airplanes, use the [flying-saucer] tag :p

Comment: Whoever created this tag was just winging it

Comment: And they were definitely with a clouded mind at that moment

Comment: The airplane tag is too broad as it stands, it can be safely burninated. Those questions with the tag that are actually about airplane-mode (which is an ok tag) should be retagged. Those who actully program airplane firmware will use the do178-b tag.

Comment: I wonder what Jefferson thinks of this tag...

Comment: @Machavity: Probably wants to migrate it to [starship].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went ahead and cleaned the tag as best I could. There were some misuses of the tag for "airplane seating" problems, but virtually all the remaining questions were about [airplane-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/airplane-mode), so I renamed the tag.

That should solve the problem.